# FileUtil does not copy ".gitignore"

Tags: ruby

I used `FileUtils.cp_r()` to copy a whole folder. All files inside that folder is copied except `.gitignore`. If I change the file's name to `gitignore` (without period), it works fine.

I'm guessing it's because the file's name is not valid for Ruby. Is there a solution for this?

This is my code:

```
require "fileutils"

module MyApp
  def self.create
    # root of the gem dir
    root = File.expand_path("..", File.dirname(__FILE__))

    # "/template" is the folder that I want to copy
    src_dir = File.join(root, "template")

    # destination is where the command prompt opened
    destination = Dir.pwd

    FileUtils.cp_r( Dir["#{src_dir}/*"], destination)
  end
end
```

I'm using Windows 8.1 Update 1. But my friend who uses Mac tested my gem and doesn't get the `.gitignore` too.

Comment: Please post the code you are using to do the operation. Are you using a glob? Are you calling the directory names directly? In a simple case like `FileUtils.cp_r 'srcdir', 'destdir'`, it should have no problem with a dotfile.

Comment: Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1.1. I will add the code in my question very soon

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski added. I simplify the code a bit. So there might be a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
Dir["#{src_dir}/*"]
```

Globbing does not include filenames starting with `.`.

Use other methods like this instead:

```
sources = Dir.entries("#{src_dir}/").reject{ |e| e == '.' || e == '..' }.map{ |e| "#{src_dir}/#{e}" }
FileUtils.cp_r(sources, destination)
```

You can also use `File::FNM_DOTMATCH`:

```
Dir.glob("#{src_dir}/*", File::FNM_DOTMATCH)
```