# Skipping Items in find Until a Path is Reached (or Passed)

Tags: shell, find

I have a long-running script that processes a very large number of files returned from a `find` statement, and which periodically stores a recently processed path. This allows the script to attempt to resume from after that path on subsequent runs.

Currently I'm doing this by running through a sorted `find` until I reach a path that is equal or greater than the last path processed.

For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmp_dir=$(mktemp -d "/tmp/tmp.$$.XXXXXX")
trap 'rm -R "$tmp_dir"; echo "$last_path" > ~/.last_path;' INT HUP TERM EXIT

last_path=$(cat ~/.last_path)
mkfifo "$tmp_dir/files"
{ find -s . -mindepth 1 -type f -print0; printf '\0'; } > "$tmp_dir/files" &
exec 5< "$tmp_dir/files"

next() { read -rd '' path <&5; }
next

if [ -n "$last_path" ]; then
    while [[ "$path" < "$last_path" || "$path" = "$last_path" ]]; do
        next
        [ -z "$path" ] && break
    done

    if [ -n "$path" ]; then
        echo "Ready to resume from: $path"
    else
        echo 'Unable to resume (start from beginning next time)'
        last_path=
        exit
    fi
fi

while [ -n "$path" ]; do
    echo "$path"
    last_path="$path"
    next
done
last_path=
```

As you can see the script will try to ensure that the last path is always written out to a file at `~/.last_path`, and when it starts it will look here to see if it should resume. If it should then it will run through the contents of the `find` command until it finds the first path to come later (alphabetically, due to the sort) compared to the last path, so that it can resume from here.

Anyway, this works fine for smaller sets of files, but it isn't especially efficient for larger sets, as a resume path that's a hundred thousand files in will require a long delay until the search reaches that point and can resume again.

My thinking was to use a `-prune` action within the `find` command in order to cut out chunks of the hierarchy that cannot possibly include the path to resume from, but I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to do this.

For example, I initially thought of doing something like:

```
-exec [[ {} < "$last_path" ]] -prune
```

However, if I wanted to reach a path of `/foo/bar` then the above rule would prune `/foo`, making this impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! I think I might have arrived at a solution using a custom function:

```
skip_path() {
    path="$1"; skip="$2"
    if [ -d "$path" ]; then
        length=${#path}
        skip=${skip:0:$length}
    fi
    [[ "$path" < "$skip" ]]; return $?
}
```

This can then be invoked like so:

```
export -f skip_path
find -s . -mindepth 1 -exec bash -c 'skip_path "$@"' -- {} "$last_path" \; -prune -or -type f -print0;
```

Seems to do the trick! It's worth nothing that `last_path` *must* come from the output of `find`, i.e - it must be identical in form to the paths that `find` uses. So if `find` is running with a relative path it will usually return paths in the form "./foo/bar" so a `last_path` of "foo/bar" won't work, and will in fact result in skipping everything, so take care where you get your `last_path` from!

Answer (score 1):

```
{ find -ds . -mindepth 1 -type f -print0; printf '\0'; } > "$tmp_dir/files"
```

That code above actually writes all output of `find` to `"$tmp_dir/files"` at once. Not sure if the fifo pipe allows holding it all at once. Does it even work without the other reading input?

Since you're using Bash, what you better do is to use process substitution. No need to use named pipes.

```
exec 5< <(exec find -ds . -mindepth 1 -type f -print0)
```

Some parts of your code can also be done without testing if `$path` is not empty:

```
while
    echo "$path"
    last_path=$path
    next
do
    :
done
```

`last_path=$(cat ~/.last_path)` can also be just `IFS= read -r last_path < ~/.last_path`.

If you want to store and read irregular paths:

```
printf '%s\0' "$last_path" > ~/.last_path
IFS= read -rd '' < ~/.last_path
```

Comment: Ah, you're right, on that first point the find should be a background process with `$tmp_dir/files` returning the results. Anyway, I'm not too worried about the specifics of the script, I know it's a bit messy but I've tried to skip a ton of cross-platfomr compatibility stuff just to give an idea of what I'm doing. The important thing is finding out how to skip quickly in `find`

Comment: @Haravikk If you really need a tool that could skip processed files and skip enumerating processed directories it should be something that you could control before it attempts to enumerate those files and `find` is probably not the tool for that. Consider using another tool. And I'd prefer Ruby. The trick is to use a hash in which you'd store paths as keys. It will tell which file or directory was already processed. When you want to save, just store the hash as a file, then restore it on resume. You'd use a recursive function. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25350139/445221) too.